How to calculate the deformation gradient between two configurations of material points?
Let's say, I have a triangular element which its initial and deformed coordinates are taken from measurements, so I have the point coordinates. Please also consider a certain rigid body translation between the states.
$\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}
P_1(x,y,t_0) \\P_2(x,y,t_0) \\ P_3(x,y,t_0)
\end{bmatrix}$ ,
$\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
P_1(x,y,t) \\P_2(x,y,t) \\ P_3(x,y,t)
\end{bmatrix}$
How can I compute the deformation gradient $\mathbf{F}$ from the given above ?
Below image is given just as an example.


First choose two sides of the undeformed triangle
$v_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\-1\end{bmatrix}$
$v_{13}=\begin{bmatrix}2.5\\3\end{bmatrix}$
Then identify the corresponding sides in the deformed triangle
$V_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}1.5\\-1.5\end{bmatrix}$
$V_{13}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}$
You know how the deformation gradient $F$ transforms a vector
$V_{12}=F v_{12}$
$V_{13}=F v_{13}$
The last two relationships give you enough equations to solve for all 4 components of $F$
$\begin{bmatrix}V_{12} &V_{13}\end{bmatrix}=F\begin{bmatrix}v_{12} &v_{13}\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}1.5 &3\\-1.5&4\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}F_{11} &F_{12}\\F_{21} &F_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}4&2.5\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$
solve the last matrix-matrix equality for $F_{11}$,$F_{12}$,$F_{21}$,$F_{22}$

What if the deformation also includes rigid body translations ? For example in the example I provided there is certain rigid body translation, therefore the change in coordinates cannot be directly assigned to deformation gradient..

@Yirmidokuz The deformation gradient, as per definition, is independent of rigid body translations. The gradient of a rigid body translation is zero.

yes $\mathbf{F}$ should be rigid body translation free when it is correctly calculated. My question is given the two states in my example how should the $\mathbf{F}$ be calculated ?

I think you need an underlying displacement field. In your problem statement, the displacement field is not specified. I would do it the following way. The deformation gradient is given by
$$
F_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf{X})}{\partial X_j} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_j} \Big(X_i + U_i \Big) = \delta_{ij} + \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial X_j}
$$
where $U_i$  is the $i^{th}$  component of the displacement field. Now, expand your solution in a finite element basis to get
$$
U_i = \sum_A N_A(X)U_{iA}
$$
Differentiate to get
$$
F_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \sum_A N_{A,j}(X)U_{iA}
$$

Thank you for the reply! However, I only have the point measurements of two configurations. Do you think it is possible to infer the displacements from these coordinates ? Eventually, with the displacements the points at $\mathbf{X}$ should transform to the points at $\mathbf{x}$

That is the issue. There could be many mappings that satisfy the point measurements of the two configurations.

I think rigid body translation should be possible to be removed from this map. The rest can be related with the deformation.
